# How to centrally align Icon to first line of a Text component in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have already built most of the component below but I am stuck on a detail. The detail is that the whole content should be vertically centered and additionally the `Icon` component should be centrally aligned to the first line of the `Text` component.(Below is the desired output)

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun MyBaseComponent(
    @DrawableRes iconResId: Int? = null,
    title: String? = null,
    subtitle: String,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    itemColor: Color
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .heightIn(min = 48.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = backgroundColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp))
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(MyTheme.spacing.double),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            iconResId?.let {
                MyIcon(iconResId = iconResId, tint = itemColor)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(end = MyTheme.spacing.double))
            }

            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(MyTheme.spacing.small)) {
                title?.let { MyTitle(text = title, color = itemColor) }
                MySubtitle(text = subtitle, color = itemColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How it looks like at the moment. Everything seems to be alright but except the icon positioning.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A simple way is to use the parent composable padding to align the top of the icon and the text:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun IconText(
) {
    val title =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do."
    val subtitle =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .heightIn(min = 48.dp)
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp))
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 40.dp, bottom = 40.dp)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_check),
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Gray),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp)
            )
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
                Text(text = subtitle, color = Color.Black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: padding align]

A more complicated way is to use 'onTextLayout' to find the location of the line:

```
@Composable
fun TextLineIcon(
    text: String,
    icon: ImageVector,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    iconRightPadding: Dp = 0.dp,
    iconLine: Int = 0,
    iconTint: Color = Color.Black
    // etc
) {
    val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = icon)
    var lineTop = 0f
    var lineBottom = 0f
    var lineLeft = 0f
    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        val imageSize = Size(icon.defaultWidth.toPx(), icon.defaultHeight.toPx())
        val rightPadding = iconRightPadding.toPx()
        Text(
            text = text,
            color = color,
            fontSize = fontSize,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            onTextLayout = { layoutResult ->
                val nbLines = layoutResult.lineCount
                if (nbLines > iconLine) {
                    lineTop = layoutResult.getLineTop(iconLine)
                    lineBottom = layoutResult.getLineBottom(iconLine)
                    lineLeft = layoutResult.getLineLeft(iconLine)
                }
            },
            modifier = modifier.drawBehind {
                with(painter) {
                    translate(
                        left = lineLeft - imageSize.width - rightPadding,
                        top = lineTop + (lineBottom - lineTop) / 2 - imageSize.height / 2,
                    ) {
                        draw(painter.intrinsicSize, colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(iconTint))
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun IconText2(
) {
    val title =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed do."
    val subtitle =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .heightIn(min = 48.dp)
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp))
    ) {
        Box {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp)
            ) {
                TextLineIcon(
                    title,
                    Icons.Filled.Check,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    iconRightPadding = 4.dp,
                    iconTint = Color.Gray
                )
                Text(text = subtitle, color = Color.Black)
                TextLineIcon(
                    title,
                    Icons.Filled.PlusOne,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    iconRightPadding = 4.dp,
                    iconLine = 1,
                    iconTint = Color.Red
                )

                Text(text = subtitle, color = Color.Black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even chose the line you want the icon to be aligned with.

Result:
[image: line align]

Answer (score 0):

Either use `padding(top = x.dp)` to offset the icon or create a different hierarchy, something like:

```
Column() {
  MyTitle() // Also align to end of composable
  Row {
     Icon()
     MySubtitle() // Align to end

  }
}
```

Might need some adjustmends but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: But what will be the value of `x.dp` as based on system font scaling this value can change

Answer (score 0):

`verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` it will align every item inside the `row` vertically. 
for example: your `row` is a size of `50.dp` and `column` which contains the two `textView` are almost equal to `45.dp`, alright? now that will aligned centerVertically that's fine but the problem is your `icon` which is size of for instance `24.dp` if we look at the ratio of `50.dp(row)` , `45.dp(column)` then `icon` which is `24.dp` pretty big according to `50.dp`, we can't  clearly see behaviour of `45.dp` according to `50.dp` but according to `24.dp` it can clearly be seen.
You have to remove `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` from the row.

**Sample:**

```
@Composable
fun AlignmentProblem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(400.dp)
                .background(Color.Cyan)
          
        ) {

            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_chat),
                contentDescription = null
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(text = "What is Lorem Ipsum?")
                Text(text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi how will you scale this when let's say your string changes bases on localisation, text size(system scling) etc? I think your design will fail badly